# How to retrieve item from another localStorage Domain?

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

I'm working on a JAVA web application which plays the role of a search engine. Its backend is developed with AngularJS. And I have a small PHP code which tries to send a data from an input text to the JAVA web app via an iframe. the data is stocked in a localStorage.

Here is below the PHP Code :

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
 function redirect(){

  var toSearch = document.getElementById('wordToSearch').innerHTML;
  console.log("toSearch : ", toSearch);
  localStorage.setItem('wordToSearch', 'bdd');
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8050/searchEngine/#/search";
  
 }

 </script>
 <form action="http://localhost:8050/searchEngine/#/search">
  <input type="text" name="word" id="wordToSearch">
    <input type="submit" value="Search"  onclick="redirect()">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Precisely, I'm trying to retrieve the "wordToSearch" item value stored within the localStorage

Here is below the code where i add my iFrame to my application :

```html
<iframe src='http://localhost:8040/test/index.php'></iframe>
```

This is the result i get in the developer tools :

[Developer Tools Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooqur.jpg)

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: give up of localstorage, try another aproach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So TL;DR, you're saying you want JavaScript code running on a page whose origin is `http://localhost:8050` to access the `localStorage` for origin `http://localhost:8040` (or vice-versa)?

You can't do that. [Web storage](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) is specific to the origin, which includes the port.

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder ; is there another way to retrieve that data (wordToSearch)?

Comment: @B.Othman: Not directly. You'll want to revisit your overall structure, and perhaps have your server-side Java code call your server-side PHP code (or vice-versa) directly.

Comment: Can't it be done with just a POST request between the PHP Code and server-side Java code ?

Comment: @B.Othman: That's what I meant by *"...have your server-side Java code call your server-side PHP code (or vice-versa) directly..."*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using cookie, set value to http://localhost:8050 and get value from http://localhost:8040. Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie